# Django: two foreign keys to users in model, get the one that's not the user who loaded the page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-1.8

I have two models that go something like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='profiles') # MyUser is my custom user model
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    def get_all_contracts(self):
        #returns all contracts associated with the profile

class Contract(models.Model):
    ...
    employee = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='employee_contracts')
    employer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='employer_contracts')
    ...
```

I want to write a method inside the Contract model that returns the `UserProfile` instance that is not the one accessing the view, so that if it's the employee accessing the dashboard, this method would return the employer and vice versa, so that I can use it like so:

```
{% for contract in user_profile.get_all_contracts %}
    <h2>The other user is {{ contract.other_user.display_name }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

In this example, `other_user` would be the method.

Is there a way to do that? I can't figure out how to detect from the method which profile is the one that loaded the page.

any help appreciated :)

Comment: This might be easier to implement as either view logic or a template filter, because the immediately easiest way to get the user making the request is `request.user`. Your `other_user` would therefore be the user of the two whose id doesn't match `request.user.id`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist How would I implement it ias view logic if I wanna use it in a for loop, and dont know how many contracts get_all_contracts is gonna return? Each contract would be with a different person also, so I don't know how to pass it in context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a template tag. Something like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_other_user_display_name(user, contract):
    try:
        return [obj for obj in [contract.employee, contract.employer] \
                if obj != user][0].display_name

        # if you don't like list comprehensions, you could do:
        # set([contract.employee, contract.employer]) - set([user])
        # but I find this syntax to be less than obvious
    except IndexError:
        return ''
```

Then in your template loop:

```
{% for contract in user_profile.get_all_contracts %}
    <h2>The other user is {% get_other_user_display_name request.user contract %}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

If you're 100% confident that the `contract.employee` and `contract.employer` relationships won't be null, you can eliminate that `IndexError` exception handler.

Alternatively, you could do this as an assignment tag if you need to access other properties of the `other_user`:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_other_user(context, contact):
    # you can get request.user from the context

    user = context['request'].user

    return [obj for obj in [contract.employee, contract.employer] if obj != user][0]
```

Then in your loop you can access whatever properties you want.

```
{% for contract in user_profile.get_all_contracts %}
    {% get_other_user contract as other_user %}
    <h2>The other user is {{ other_user.display_name }}</h2>
    <p>Their email is: {{ other_user.email }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is there any way to make a tag for any property? I didn't show in the example, but i wanna show more than just the display name in each for loop. something like `{% get_other_user request.user contract property_name %}` ?

Comment: Sure. I'll add an example of how you can do an assignment tag.

Comment: thanks, Brandon! I read the docs on assignment tags. Good idea. I'm gonna use one of those.